# Powershell string exacto entre comillas

Tags: string, powershell

Tengo un archivo .message con los parametros de un correo.
¿De que forma podría guardar en variable las X que estan entre comillas?. Las X son el cuerpo del correo y pueden cambiar segun el archivo.

```
" Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity body";s:11:"XXXXXXXXXXX";
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a PowerShell de windows seria de la siguiente manera:

```
PS C:\> $exis = XXXXXXXXXXX
PS C:\> $x =' Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity body";s:11:"'+$exis+'";"'
PS C:\> $x
 Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity body";s:11:"XXXXXXXXXXX";"
```

Si no es así, deberías explicarte mejor a que entorno te refieres

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```sh
$letras = "hola"
$numeros = "123"
" Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity body";s:$numeros:"$letras";
```